# Проблемы с запуском Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10

Обновил Windows и начались проблемы.

Сначала комп начал зависать при операциях с файлами

Потом в диспетчер появился процесс "Системные прерывания", который занимал до 90% ЦП (уточню, что драйвера все обновлены)

И он какой-то странный. При запуске Диспетчера задач 70-90% и через пару секунд приходил в норму. Закрываю ДЗ и опять тоже самое.

Прошли сутки.

В один прекрасный момент вылез экран смерти. Комп перезагрузился

Сейчас при включении ноутбука черный экран...

Что делать?

Answer (score 1):

Вставьте загрузочную флешку с любой операционной системой какая вам нравится и выполните переустановку ОС

Comment: Переустановка запускается, но мне желательно вернуть то что было. У меня на диске C важные файлы

Comment: @ДенисНебесный С системы на флешке пробовали? Вам достаточно просто скопировать нужные файлы с диска под такой системой